# Platform Independent Mobile Development SDK for a small task

Tags: mobile, cordova, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I want to create an mobile phone app which can run on more than one mobile OS. with a little bit of browsing it became clear that I can use SDK's like [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) or [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) so that my app would run on any mobile OS. my problem is that i dont know which SDK should I use ?  All that i require from my app is that 
1. It should run on the mobile 24x7.
2. It should have access to the GPS functionality of the Mobile phone.
3. It should send a data string to a specified server.

Should I work with Phonegap or Appcelerator or are their any other better SDK's for this tiny task ?
Thank you

Comment: Don't know about Appcelerator works as I've never used it, but Phonegap would do. You can access the device's GPS (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html) and could send data through ajax calls, as the application would be implemented in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to go with Appcelerator titanium because it gives native look to your application..., as the application would be implemented in javascript.

please go through this link

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap works on 7 mobile platforms vs 2 mobile platforms for Appcelerator

Answer (score 0):

I would say, from my own experience, in order to create a multi-platform application with a native look/feel and native performance it is best to go with Appcelerator Titanium.

It is very easy to have an application run on both iOS and Android with minimal change of code.

Either Titanium (JavaScript) or the combination of PhoneGap and Sencha Touch (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) will suit your purposes, however, as stated above, I advise using Titanium for the native feel.